# \pageref, but for columns

Tags: cross-referencing, two-column

I need to point to a label on a page, but as my text is layed out in two columns, I'd also like to include the column (1 or 2). Is there a way to find out which column a label is in?

```
\documentclass{icgg}
\begin{document}
\section{First chapter}
\label{explanation}
Some text explaining some things.
...
... see page \pageref{explanation} for ...

\end{document}
```

I'd like to use something like:

```
see page \pageref{explanation}, column \columnref{explanation} for ...
```

Possible?

ps. the document class is provided by someone else and it defines the two-column format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Where does `icgg.cls` come from? Can you give us a link to it?

Comment: icgg.cls is provided by the people who run the conference which this paper is for. I've put the cls class in my dropbox folder: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38313625/icgg.cls

Comment: Related: [Detecting current column in multicol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108793/16967)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an attempt.

The class `icgg.cls` loads `hyperref`. We create a new command `\collabel` which is executed each time a `\label` command is issued.

If, for example, you issue `\label{foo}` a new label called `col:foo` is created at the same point of the document. if you want to know the column to which `\label{foo}` refers to, you have to use the command `\columnref{col:foo}`.

Here's an example (replace `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} \usepackage{hyperref}` with `\documentclass{icgg}` in your document):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum} %only for the example

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\oldlabel\label
\newcommand*\collabel[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{col:#1}{%
        {\if@firstcolumn 1\else 2\fi}%
        {}%
        {}%
        {}%
        {}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\renewcommand*\label[1]{%
  \collabel{#1}\oldlabel{#1}
}
\def\columnref#1{%
  \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@firstoffive
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First section}\label{sec:first}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Second section}\label{sec:second}
\lipsum[1-3]\label{sec:third}

Section \ref{sec:first} starts at page \pageref{sec:first} in column \columnref{col:sec:first}, 
while section \ref{sec:second} starts at page \pageref{sec:second} in column \columnref{col:sec:second}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Zoom on the relevant part:

[image]

Note that the command `\if@firstcolumn` sometimes fails to detect the right column, so you may have some wrong references.