# Making `\AtBeginDocument{\pretocmd{\label}{##1}...` work

Tags: labels, xpatch

I want to patch `\label`, involving `#1`, and it seems that with `hyperref`, you have to do so after `\begin{document}` or using `\AtBeginDocument`. (The code should work without `hyperref`, too.) So this is what I tried, and it fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Attempt 1 - does nothing
% \pretocmd{\label}{#1}{}{err}

% Attempt 3 - fails (err)
% \AtBeginDocument{\pretocmd{\label}{#1}{}{err}}

% Attempt 4 - fails (err)
\AtBeginDocument{\pretocmd{\label}{##1}{}{err}}

\begin{document}
    % Attempt 2 - works, inelegant
    % \pretocmd{\label}{#1}{}{err}

    Label name is \label{mylabel}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve with `#1` in `\pretocmd`. What should `#1` do there? -- it is not accessible there!

Comment: Just an explanation, no solution: When `\AtBeginDocument` saves its argument for later use, it tokenizes its argument. In this process `#` gets doubled to `##`, which is what `\pretocmd` later adds to the `\label` command.

Comment: My three failing attempts may be wrong, but attempt 2 shows what I want: use (not output - use) #1. I chose to output it in the examples for reasons of simplicity, but in my application, `showkeys` etc would not work.

Comment: @gernot: Sorry, I was on the wrong track. I tried to use `\pretocmd` once and accessing of `#1` , but it failed, because I did not realize that the command hat moving arguments. I've forgotten about that this was the cause of the failure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see no real way to overcome this chicken and egg problem with `etoolbox` (or `xpatch` that's just a wrapper over its macros). You simply can't use `#1` in the replace part of `\patchcmd` or the analogous part in `\pretocmd` or `\apptocmd` when the command is in the argument to another command, in this case `\AtBeginDocument`.

There is a way out with `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \makeatletter
  % \A is the start of string anchor, \cP\# is l3regex for 'parameter token'
  \regexpatchcmd{\label}{\A}{\cP\#1}{}{\err}%
  \makeatother
}

\begin{document}

Label name is \label{mylabel}.

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, packages such as `showkeys` or `showlabels` are much better for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! This has been very useful in making http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351155/30810 independent of whether `hyperref` is loaded.