# Finding a reference position with zref

Tags: positioning, zref

I have a solution for [\pageref, but for top/middle/bottom of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350527/pageref-but-for-top-middle-bottom-of-the-page); however, with `IEEEtran`, `\maketitle` interferes with determining the top-left corner of the text area as a reference position.

You will see the problem in this MWE: Without `\maketitle`, `\location` shows the vertical distance to the beginning of the text area; however, with `\maketitle`, it shows the vertical distance to the beginning of the text are after the `\maketitle` block, although I would expect `\AtBeginDocument` to be executed first. I can add `\hspace{0}pt` before `\zsavepos{loc:ref}` to force LaTeX into horizontal mode, and the results appear to be correct then. However, this adds an empty page to output that I cannot get rid of without impacting positions again.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
%   \hspace{0pt}%
    \zsavepos{loc:ref}}

\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{counter}
\newlength{\diff}
\newcommand{\location}{%
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \stepcounter{counter}%
    \zsavepos{here\thecounter}%
    \setlength{\diff}{\zposy{loc:ref}sp-\zposy{here\thecounter}sp}%
    \the\diff}

\title{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}

\usepackage[columnwise,switch]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
%   \maketitle

    \foreach \n in {1,...,58}{\location

    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a good solution? It seems to work for me:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\zsavepos{loc:ref}}

\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{counter}
\newlength{\diff}
\newcommand{\location}{%
    \hspace{0pt}%
    \stepcounter{counter}%
    \zsavepos{here\thecounter}%
    \setlength{\diff}{\zposy{loc:ref}sp-\zposy{here\thecounter}sp}%
    \the\diff}

\title{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle

    \foreach \n in {1,...,58}{\location

    }
\end{document}
```