# Modify multicol environment based on content

Tags: multicol

When having the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
            \blindtext
        \end{minipage}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

my last minipage will end up as a left column. Is there a possibility to detect if the right column is empty, and if yes, to center the last minipage?

Comment: Very much the same as [Detecting current column in multicol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108793/detecting-current-column-in-multicol#109398)

Comment: The last minipage in your MWE ends up in the right column, not left. The 2nd minipage goes in the left column. With 1/2/3 before `\blindtext` : http://i.imgur.com/3k6RAnw.png

Comment: @alwaysask: Hmm, can I then make it rather like <left-right-left-right-center>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `tcbraster` environment with the last box centered.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[blankest, raster columns=2, raster equal height, raster halign=center, raster column skip=5mm, raster row skip=5mm]
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \lipsum[2]
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between tcbraster and multicol?

Comment: @arc_lupus Within a `multicol` environment, all its contents will be organized into as many columns you defined. As soon as contents fills the first column, second is started, later third, etc, contents flows from one column to the next as soon as the previous is completed. On the other side, `tcbraster` is an environment based on boxes not flows. In this case every minipage defines a box which is inserted into the raster.

Comment: @arc_lupus If you want organize `boxes` as left-right-left-right-center, you can use `tcbraster`.