# How can I detect when I'm at the top of column?

Tags: multicol

I have a series of text blocks in a 2-column layout, using `multicol`. Each block of text is wrapped in a `minipage` environment to ensure that all the contained text appears in the same column. I would like to separate these minipages with a horizontal rule or other decoration, but I don't want the rule to appear if it's at the top of a column.

Clearly, I could add a parameter that would manually suppress the rule, but I'm looking for a way to detect the situation automatically and format appropriately. For the MWE below, that means the line should only appear between the final two paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{segmented}{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\hrule\bigskip
}{\bigskip
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{segmented}
        \lipsum[1]  
    \end{segmented}
    \begin{segmented}
        \lipsum[2]  
    \end{segmented}
    \begin{segmented}
        \lipsum[3]  
    \end{segmented}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Detection might not be easy; see [Detecting current column in `multicol`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108793/5764).

Comment: @Werner, The underlying detection certainly isn't easy, but the basic problem already seems solved in that link and folded into `multicol`, so thanks for pointing it out. I've put an answer below that builds on `\docolaction`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you'd like to get?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}% for avoiding too many underfull boxes
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{segmented}
 {%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}\par
  \bigskip
  \cleaders\vbox{\hrule width\linewidth}\vskip0.4pt
  \bigskip
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{segmented}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{segmented}
\begin{segmented}
\lipsum[2]  
\end{segmented}
\begin{segmented}
\lipsum[3]  
\end{segmented}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly the result I'm looking for. Can you confirm or correct my understanding of how this works? `\cleaders` is a TeX command that repeats the `\vbox` enough times to fit within `\vskip0.4pt`, which means that the rule won't appear at the bottom of a column, as the `\vskip` becomes 0 there.

Comment: @KarlHagen Since the rule is 0.4pt high, there will be just one; but leaders are like glue, so they disappears at page/column breaks

Comment: ah just see that @egreg did kind of the same while I was collecting screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a better way to do this, but @Werner's link gave me this idea. It relies on the `colaction` feature of `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\numdef{\columnnumber}{0}
\newcommand{\conditionalrule}[1]{
    \ifnumequal{#1}{\columnnumber}{\hrule}{}
    \global\numdef{\columnnumber}{#1}
    }

\newenvironment{segmented}{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \docolaction{\conditionalrule{1}}{}{\conditionalrule{2}}\bigskip
}{\bigskip
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{segmented}
            \lipsum[1]  
        \end{segmented}
        \begin{segmented}
            \lipsum[2]  
        \end{segmented}
        \begin{segmented}
            \lipsum[3]  
        \end{segmented}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: multicol line]

If anyone has a more elegant/efficient solution, I'd be happy to accept their answer, so I'm holding off on accepting my own answer for a little while.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I added an example output image to better demonstrate what your code does. Feel free to roll back the edit if you so wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can let TeX determine the position (which works within or outside multicol):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l__condline_dim
\box_new:N \l__condline_box

% #1 skip produced
% #2 vertical correction of material
% #3 material 
% #4 break penalty after (if forbidden the only place to break is before

\cs_new:Npn \condline:nn #1#2#3#4 
  {
    \par
    \hbox_set_to_wd:Nnn \l__condline_box \columnwidth {\hfil #3 \hfil}
%
    \dim_set:Nn \l__condline_dim
        { \box_ht:N \l__condline_box +
          \box_dp:N \l__condline_box }
%
    \skip_vertical:n { #1 / 2 - \prevdepth + #2 - \l__condline_dim / 2 }
    \nobreak    
%
    \cleaders \copy \l__condline_box \vskip \l__condline_dim
    \nobreak    
%
    \skip_vertical:n { #1 / 2 - \parskip  - #2 - \l__condline_dim / 2 }
    \penalty #4 \relax 
%
    \dim_set:Nn \prevdepth { 0pt }
  }

% document level command
%
% \condline * < correction > [ skip ] { material }
%
% all arguments optional

\DeclareDocumentCommand\condline 
  { s  D<>{3pt} O{\baselineskip} G{$*\quad*\quad*$} }
  { \IfBooleanTF #1
      { \condline:nn {#3} {#2} {#4} {10000} }
      { \condline:nn {#3} {#2} {#4} {0} }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \lipsum[1]
  \condline{...........}
  line1\\  line2\\  line3\\  line4\\ line5\\  
  add two extra lines
  and the stars below will vanish!\\
 % line9\\  line10\\
  LAST LAST LAST
  \condline{$* \quad * \quad * $}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

  \condline<-5pt>{\hrulefill}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[3]
  \condline{\hrulefill}
  \lipsum[4]
  \condline[2\baselineskip]{---With star this line would vanish }
  \lipsum[5]
  \condline{\dotfill}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

(the code is a bit of a mixture of expl3 + ordinary LaTeX as expl3 doesn't yet have all tools for text processing (like handling penalties))

The result is:

[image]

And if we add 2 lines in the first multicol and use the star form of `\condline` in the second one we will get:

[image]

The right bottom column now appears to be too short but that is understandable as now the only break is before the `\condline` and the line vanishes if the break is taken there (just like the line with asterisks in the first multicol vanished at the break.

Answer (score 1):

A proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}%

\newcount\myy\newcount\ymax
\newcounter{myx}\setcounter{myx}{1}

\typeout{\themyx}
\newcommand\donotruleattop{%
    \stepcounter{myx}
    \zsaveposy{\themyx}%
    \typeout{y position of \themyx: \zposy{\themyx}}
    \myy=\numexpr\zposy{\themyx}\relax
    \ifnum\myy>\ymax\relax\else\hrule\bigskip\fi
}%
\newcommand{\gaugeymax}{%
\stepcounter{myx}
\zsaveposy{\themyx}
\ymax=\numexpr\zposy{\themyx}-256\relax
}

\newenvironment{segmented}{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\donotruleattop
}{\bigskip
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}\gaugeymax 
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{segmented}
        \lipsum[1] 
    \end{segmented}
    \begin{segmented}
        \lipsum[2] 
    \end{segmented}
    \begin{segmented}
        \lipsum[3] 
    \end{segmented}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a shortcoming: The number `256` appearing in the definition is hard-coded, and might have to be adjusted if you change the layout of the document.

Nevertheless, this might be a starting point for a smoother solution. And it is both a counter-example and confirmation of @Werner's statement, depending on what you mean by easy.

Obviously, this construction is not specific to multicolumn.