# How to reference page and column in a two-column text

Tags: cross-referencing, two-column

Does it exist a command like pageref with which I can indicate the column too? (I am writing a two-column text and I would like to give an indication more precise than the simple page).

Comment: Do you just want to print `1` or `2` as the output?

Comment: Yes, or something like 5/1 and 5/2 (or 5-1 and 5-2) for page and column. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting/tracking the (current) column [is not easy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108793/5764). However, a somewhat simplistic yet effective way of identifying the column can be done by labelling the x-coordinate on the page. If that x-coordinate is less than half the page width, you should be within the left (first) column, otherwise you're in the right (second) column.

Here is that implementation using the `savepos` module from [`zref`](//ctan.org/pkg/zref):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\newcommand{\columnlabel}[1]{\label{#1}\zsaveposx{#1}}
\newcommand{\columnref}[1]{%
  \ifdim\zposx{#1}sp<.5\pdfpagewidth
    left% column 1
  \else
    right% column 2
  \fi
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\lipsum[1-5]
\textcolor{red}{\columnlabel{important}Some important text}%

\lipsum[6-10]

See \textcolor{red}{page~\pageref{important} (\columnref{important} column)}.

\end{document}
```

You could update `\columnref` to output something of the format `<page>-<column>` in the following way:

```
% Output <page>-<column> as a reference
\newcommand{\columnref}[1]{%
  \pageref{#1}-%
  \ifdim\zposx{#1}sp<.5\pdfpagewidth
    1% column 1
  \else
    2% column 2
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a minor esthetic thing. I am sorry but I do not undersand how to properly write a code section in a comment. I want to add an hyperlink with something like this
`code`
    \lipsum[1-5]  
    \phantomsection\label{mylabel}{Important text}
    \lipsum[6-10]
    Check out in the document at Pag.~\columnref{mylabel}.  
`code`
The red box of the link is only around the page number. Is it poss ible to make it larger so as to include the column number too?

Comment: @Gippo: Use the definitions in [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/pz2JcM64).